# How do I get the age of everyone in my people array

Tags: c#

My class is:

```
public class Person
{
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;
    private DateTime _birthdate;

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthdate)
    {
        _firstname = firstname;
        _lastname = lastname;
        _birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public string Firstname
    { get { return _firstname; } }

    public string Lastname
    { get { return _lastname; } }

    public DateTime Birthdate
    { get { return _birthdate; } }
```

Here is my method I am accessing in order to get everyone's age:

```
public int getAge()
{
    TimeSpan ts =DateTime.Now - _birthdate;
    int year = (int)ts.TotalDays / 365;
    return year;
}
```

My form:

```
namespace May22_StructClassObj_HW
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DateTime[] birth = new DateTime[20];
        Person[] People = new Person[20];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a class Person with the following fields _firstname, _lastname, _birthDate(DateTime Type) Add constructor, properties (get only) and a method GetAge that returns the age (int) of a person. 
            // In Form1, Create an array of Person objects to hold 20 people
            // In Form1_Load: Populate the array with 20 Person objects

            // Add Gui to display all the people in the list (first and last names, birthdate, and age
            // Add Gui 
            //people[0] = new Person("John","Stockton", DateTime.)

            string[] first = new string[20] { "Scott", "Ramona", "Todd", "Melissa", "Naomi", "Leland", "Conor", "Julie", "Armondo", "Leah", "Frank", "Peter", "Ila", "Mandy", "Sammy", "Gareth", "Garth", "Wayne", "Freddy", "Mark" };

            string[] last = new string[20] { "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Carrel", "MaloyTheBeautiful", "Johnson", "Smith", "Sinatra", "Clemens", "Eels", "Johnson", "Eels", "Thompson", "Brooks", "World", "Crugar", "Thomas" };

            birth[0] = new DateTime(1987, 2, 7);
            birth[1] = new DateTime(1962, 5, 9);
            birth[2] = new DateTime(1984, 1, 4);
            birth[3] = new DateTime(1977, 4, 1);
            birth[4] = new DateTime(1983, 2, 8);
            birth[5] = new DateTime(1979, 4, 1);
            birth[6] = new DateTime(1965, 9, 9);
            birth[7] = new DateTime(1968, 1, 2);
            birth[8] = new DateTime(1980, 2, 7);
            birth[9] = new DateTime(1982, 2, 7);
            birth[10] = new DateTime(1984, 12, 4);
            birth[11] = new DateTime(1968, 11, 9);
            birth[12] = new DateTime(1968, 2, 8);
            birth[13] = new DateTime(1975, 5, 2);
            birth[14] = new DateTime(1945, 5, 3);
            birth[15] = new DateTime(1969, 4, 6);
            birth[16] = new DateTime(1987, 1, 4);
            birth[17] = new DateTime(1976, 3, 5);
            birth[18] = new DateTime(1989, 8, 6);
            birth[19] = new DateTime(1988, 2, 9);

            // Populate Array Person[] People = new Person[20];   
            for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++)
            {
                People[i] = new Person(first[i], last[i], birth[i]);
            }

        }

        private void btnDisAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++)
            {
                richTxtDisplay.AppendText("Name: " + People[i].Firstname + "\t" + People[i].Lastname + "\t" + " BirthDate: " + People[i].Birthdate + "\n\n");
                //richTxtDisplay.AppendText(People[i].ToString());
                //richTxtDisplay.AppendText(People[i].Firstname + People[i].Lastname + People[i].Birthdate + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem here:

Here is my button that I am using to call the method and have it give me the age of everyone in my Person array. But I know this is wrong. So someone please guide me through it.

```
private void btnGetAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++)
    {
        Person Per = 
            new Person(People[i].Firstname, People[i].Lastname, People[i].Birthdate);
        Per.getAge();
    }
}
```

I have listed where my problem is. Basically all I want to do is call the method and display all the ages of everyone in my Person array. There are twenty people and I want to show their age. I do believe my code is perfect to get the age in my method in my class but I'm unsure whether I created a new instance right in order to use the method.

Comment: Fyi you could eliminate all those leading _ backing fields if you change the properties to use private setters. Also you should probably do your homework yourself.

Comment: How about putting your whole project here and paying us for it ?

Comment: This is my own hw considering in my college we aren't graded on it. Thnks for you input however. Srry if i have led you to thinking that im a cheat but Im not. I appreciate your time however thx

Comment: You do realise getAge will not always be accurate? You're assuming there's always 365 days in a year...

Comment: Thx The and I am aware of LeapYear however I wasn't worrying about that.

Comment: As long as it's definitely homework and not work for a client.

Comment: Lol I am not that good yet. LOL I will take that as a compliment if you really think a client would take me on hahaha. No I have a final in three weeks and I am going through my stuff that for some reason I didn't finish. I am in college and is my second qrter. I would think that this is super sloppy work for a client lolz

Comment: Hey asawyer what do you mean private setters?

Comment: @ScottKennedy  `public string Firstname { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Person.Length; i++)
{
   Person[i].getAge();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean People[i],getAge();

Comment: Also i would like to display all their ages

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ to get all person's age. But as you've not told us where you want to display this info and how you want to join all ages, i assume that you want to show it as string in a TextBox (or somewhere else) and split the lines by `Environment.NewLine` :

```
var allPersonAge = People.Select(p => p.GetAge());
richTxtDisplay.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allPersonAge);
```

By the way, this is a more accurate way to calculate the age in years:

```
public int getAge()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
    int age = now.Year - _birthdate.Year;
    if (_birthdate> now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Person person in People)
{
int age = person.getAge();
//Do something with the age
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using LINQ

```
List<int> result = People.Select(p => p.GetAge()).ToList();
```

Comment: I will need to start looking into LINQ. I Just started oop a few mos ago and I am eager to move forward. I appreciate this. thx

Comment: You seem pretty good with this site. How do i give really good feeback to people. SOmething that will help their ratings?

Comment: @ScottKennedy: When you like a answer click on the uparrow next to answer to upvote it so that it means that answer is good. More Upvotes like yours will bring that answer on top. When an answer given to question which you asked works for you. accept that answer a marked by clicking on empty tick arrow below upvote or downvote. Then a green color will be filled in that answer informing that that answer is accepted by asker.